# put variables into function

Tags: php, function, variables

```
<?php
echo test(); 
$a = "123";

function test(){
global $b;
b =$a;
return $b;
}
?>
```

I want to get the value from another form, so I setup a function, but why can't show the value at test()

Comment: Both njk and I have provided you with correct solutions below. Please select one as an answer, thank you.

Comment: @JamesKirby — Have patience. Give the asker time to examine answers, test them and determine if they really do answer the question. Also note that (at the time of writing) the asker *can't* select an answer as there is an enforced delay on stackoverflow.

Comment: Why isn't the standard response to people using "global" to beat them around the head with a wet mackerel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$a` is out of scope, declared after the function call and you have a syntax error. You need `global $a`.

```
$a = "123";
echo test( ); 

function test( ) {
    global $a;
    $b = $a;
    return $b;
}
```

**Result**

```
123
```

Take a look at [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Dear, 
I can't declared $a before the function because I want pass the value $b to another <form>, have another method can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot populate a variable like this: `b = $a` you need to use the proper PHP syntax, so: `$b = $a`.

Secondly, "njk" got it right, you need to declare the variable as a global as it's out of scope, so using `global $a` will work.

Finally, it'll only work if you pre-define the variable BEFORE calling the function, so this is how it'd look:

```
$a = 123;

function test() {

  global $a;

  $b = $a;

  return $b;

}

echo test();
```

That will return this result:

```
123
```

Hope that helps.